# How to send encrypted (3DES) data into aqueduct without getting any error?

Tags: request, dart, capture, aqueduct

I m using Aqueduct 3.0. I need to learn How to capture post request in Aqueduct 3.0?

My Request: http://127.0.0.1:8888/login/ziD7v0Ul99vmNWnxJRxZIiTY4zakNoq8GjM+oHROYz/YTHnd3NH1XfHRULY0jaHU

Get a Response:
[INFO] aqueduct: GET /login/ziD7v0Ul99vmNWnxJRxZIiTY4zakNoq8GjM+oHROYz/YTHnd3NH1XfHRULY0jaHU 11ms 404

my channel.dart routing

```
// TODO: connect to Socket **********
router.route('/login/[:value]').link(() {
  return new LoginController();
  //..contentType = ContentType.TEXT;
});
```

my LoginController.dart

```
import 'package:aqueduct/aqueduct.dart';
import 'package:niyaziapi/niyaziapi.dart';
import 'package:niyaziapi/util/niyaziGetPrivate.dart';
import 'package:niyaziapi/util/niyaziSetPrivate.dart';

class LoginController extends Controller {
  String _xCustomerToken;
  String _xCustomerName;
  String _xPrivate;
  String _xResult;
  String _xRequestValue;
  String _xReply;

  @override
  Future<RequestOrResponse> processRequest(Request request) async {
    String tempData = request.toString();
    print("tempDate: $tempData"); // can’t print
    try {
      if (request.path.variables.containsKey('value')) {
        _xPrivate = (request.path.variables['value']).trim();
        print("_xPrivate: $_xPrivate");
        var decryptedData = await getPrivate(_xPrivate);
        var decryptedList = decryptedData.split(":_:");
        decryptedData = null;

        decryptedData = "Q101:_:" + decryptedList[2].toString() + ":_:" + decryptedList[3].toString();
        print(decryptedData);

        var socket = await Socket.connect('192.168.1.22', 1024);
        socket.write("$decryptedData\r\n");

        await for (var data in socket) {
          _xReply = new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
          var list = _xReply.split(":_:");
          _xCustomerToken = list[2].toString();
          _xCustomerName = list[3].toString();

          });
          _xResult = "$_xCustomerToken:_:$_xCustomerName";
          var encryptedData = await setPrivate(_xResult);
          return new Response.ok("$encryptedData");
        }
      } else {
        return new Response.ok("404: Wrong Request");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return new Response.ok("404: $e.errorMessage");
    }
  }
}
```

when I testing I found that my code works. Only reason that I am sending 3DES data and has + and / character in it.

If you look at closely in first request, there is a + and / character in data which give me an error.
/login/ziD7v0Ul99vmNWnxJRxZIiTY4zakNoq8GjM+oHROYz/YTHnd3NH1XfHRULY0jaHU 19ms 404

on the other hand if I remove those character than I get perfect response.
/login/ziD7v0Ul99vmNWnxJRxZIiTY4zakNoq8GjMoHROYzYTHnd3NH1XfHRULY0jaHU 13 ms 200

So, question comes how to send encrypted (3DES) data into aqueduct without getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

Going to Like Aqueduct twice :)

**It was very simple:** 
var _xPrivate = (request.path.variables['value']).trim(); **change to:**

```
var _xPrivate = request.path.remainingPath;
print("request: $_xPrivate");
```